# Закрытие окна через usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf

Собственно вопрос.  Были мысли сделать подобное через relative source, но как это передать в код - не знаю. Желательно с минимальным количеством кода, выходящего за пределы UserControl'a

Comment: А фреймворк используете какой-нибудь?

Comment: Не очень понятно "mvvm" но при этом "пределы UserControla". Можно в code-behind контрола вызвать Window.GetWindow(this) и получить окно у которого и вызвать Close(). Но причем тут mvvm

Comment: @vitidev оформите `Window.GetWindow(this)`, отмечу как ответ. А на счет mvvm - вдруг был какой-то более изящный вариант, подходящий под концепцию mvvm. Но тут и без него обойдусь.

Comment: Да конечно есть варианты и под mvvm. Все упирается в то, кто инициирует событие закрытия - вид или вьюмодель. Или кто должен утвердить закрытие, а то вдруг закрыть в данный момент нельзя.

Comment: @vitidev Событие закрытия инициализируется по нажатию на кнопку в UserControl'e. На счет утверждения закрытия - тут ситуация интересная. Так как это UC - наверное логично будет передавать это через DP, а DP привязывать к основной VM. Хотя если предложите лучшие вариант - буду благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос все равно туманный, поэтому я пройдусь по верхам.

**Инициатор закрытия: ViewModel**

ViewModel не знает про вид, а знает только о себе (ну и о инфраструктуре конечно) и потому может сообщить о необходимости "закрыть" только косвенно:

1. Завести обычное событие RequestClose, на который подпишется вид.
2. Завести обычное INPC свойство, которое сможет использовать вид. Например `bool DialogResult {get;set;}`. (я предпочитаю это, особенно для диалоговых окон)
3. Да хоть через Messenger (инфраструктура) событие послать (упомянуто "до кучи")

**Инициатор закрытия: вид**

Можно получить текущее окно из контрола путем `Window.GetWindow(this)` и вызвать у него Close() и будет эффект, как от кнопки закрытия окна со всеми вытекающими.

Вид **знает** о ViewModel и потому варианты "кто кого вызывает и опрашивает" ограничивает лишь фантазия. Я лучше приведу несколько примеров.

**Окно с процессом операции. Закрытие запрещено**

Определяем в окне хендлер события OnClosing и проверяя свойство вида vm.IsBusy отменяем закрытие окна `e.handled = true`

**Окно с процессом операции. Остановить и закрыть**

Обычно есть кнопка "Стоп". Биндим ее на команду vm CancelCommand, которая прервет операцию и по результату вызовет RequestClose, и окно закроется. Попутно полезно определить свойство IsStopping и отслеживая его через тригеры менять контент кнопки на "Останавливаемся..."

С кнопкой закрытия окна сложнее. Она вызваем OnClosing. В OnClosing достаем vm и вызываем у него какой нибудь vm.Cancel(). ViewModel прерывает операцию и вызывает RequestClose, на которую подписан вид. Вид получив уведомление от RequestClose закрывает себя Close() - и тут снова вызывается OnClosing (получается зацикливание). Поэтому OnClosing должен проверять флаг вьюмодели IsBusy, что никаких операций не происходит и можно закрыть. (Также можно получить deadlock, который придется разруливать через Task.Yield() - хоть где то он пригодился)
Ну и конечно не забыть где нибудь написать "Останавливаемся..." если это не мгновенно.

**Обычный диалог с формой и 2 кнопки: "Сохранить" и "Отмена"**

Кнопку "Сохранить" биндим на команду SaveCommand. ViewModel при успешном результате вызывает RequestClose и окно закрывается. При неуспешном (например валидация) не вызывает.

Кнопку "Отмена" биндим на команду CancelCommand(CloseCommand), которая просто вызывает RequestClose и окно закрывается

Кнопки закрытия окна по хорошему тут быть не должно, но если есть, то она либо не вредит, если вся работа выполняется в UI, либо мудрить весь огород с OnClosing/IsBusy

**ps**: Не стоит забывать, что биндинг окна на DialogResult, работу с кнопкой "закрытия окна", `Window.GetWindow(this).Close()` - все это можно скрыть за набором кастомных attached property и code-behind будет пуст

**ps2:** Если происходит асинхронная работа, то не забывать про защиту от повторного клика на кнопку/контрол или несвоевременного клика на кнопку "закрытия окна"